Content-Security-Policy suddenly stopped working for iframes
I have the following Content-Security-Policy in my htaccess that worked fine until 5 hours ago:
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self' js.stripe.com; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none';"

Suddenly, a page without any reference to stripe or any hidden stripe file download started giving the following error message in the Console:

Refused to frame because it violates the following Content Security
Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' js.stripe.com".

I checked and rechecked, there's no mention of Stripe in my code. What's happening?

The likelihood is that Stripe.js is included in all pages in your application due to how it is imported/initialised. Stripe recommends that you import Stripe.js on all pages in order for fraud detection and prevention. If that is the case, you will likely need to update the policies to apply to all routes/pages.

You might be right. But I checked many times and there's no mention of stripe anywhere on this page. It's not in the code. It doesn't appear in network activity. Do you know how else I can check?
